# Media query for differentiating between phones & Desktop

Tags: css, media-queries

I have seen many different media queries for detecting if the user is using a phone or a desktop. However for many devices now the gap between resolution, ratios and many other things overlaps between high end devices (such as the S8), laptops and low end phones.

My question is, if I want a style sheet for phones, which include all phones and one for desktops, is there a media query to use that is best or should I take a different approach maybe with JavaScript

The landscape and portrait approach works until the soft key board is used and the phone re-considers it as landscape

Examples below no longer work on all devices as they have become out dated.

```
@media only screen and (orientation : portrait)
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
@media only screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9)
```

Comment: Well that’s the general problem with designing “for devices” ... and with ever new devices and resolutions coming out, there is no real “solution” in sight either. Which is why IMHO it makes more sense to base your media queries and breakpoints on the needs of your _content_. If my phone had a large enough screen to show the same as a desktop computer - then why force a “phone view” on me in the first place …?

Comment: The physical phone size is staying the same however, pixel density and resolution are higher. Meaning a phone view would still be required as it would be too small for the user to comfortably view

Comment: As long as you base your media queries on CSS pixels and not device pixels, that is not a real issue either.

Comment: why does the media query "@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" Fail to work on some higher end phones?

Comment: You can use [device-picel-ratio](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) so you can tell that even though there are 1000 pixels, they resolution is much higher. You can also define your breakpoints in [cm/inches instead of pixels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_measurement_units.htm)

Comment: would this affect high end laptop screens too?

Comment: @ChristopherCraven Did you even read the link?

Comment: Reading it now but am confused if it will affect laptop screens too

Comment: @ChristopherCraven Use cm/inches and you don't have to worry about resolution.

Comment: I dont think that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but I usually stick to the breakpoints defined by Bootstrap V4 even if it's not a Bootstrap project. I find that it's a nice range to develop in and more times than not I only have specific styles in the larger breakpoints (as I'm developing for mobile first).

If you only want to use two breakpoints I'd probably suggest < 768px and > 768px but you might have people with varying opinions on that. You'll definitely have edge cases with certain devices.

Comment: thanks chris, ill give this a go. I am still confused on the difference between device pixles and css pixles